# Replacing hyphen and merging the variable in sql

Tags: sql

I have 'zipcode' column with value 19707-1234. I have to remove hyphen in between and change the value to 197071234. Can anyone please help me, how to do this using sql query irrespective of index?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We a have built in replace function,you can use that

```
Declare @zipcode varchar(50)='19707-1234'

Select replace(@zipcode,'-','')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the replace function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(zipcode, '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inbuilt [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186862.aspx) function of SQL.

```
SELECT REPLACE('19707-1234','-','');
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql I have used below query for replacing hyphen

```
*SELECT concat( SUBSTRING_INDEX('0125-3256','-',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX('0125-3256','-',-1)) as replace_hypen*
```

Output of this query = '01253256'

So you can use for zipcode code column

```
SELECT concat( SUBSTRING_INDEX(zipcode,'-',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(zipcode,'-',-1)) as replace_hypen
```